# How do I unlearn words?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

I just got the new Samsung Galaxy S5 and I was texting and I accidentally held down one of the words that pops up when I start texting and this box popped up saying that whatever word will be removed from learned words. So now every time I type the word "the" it changes it to their or them or anything similar and its really annoying. Because this is a new phone I have no idea where to go or what to look for. Please help!

Comment: In my Swype keyboard that feature is available by long pressing the learned word on the suggestion list

Answer (score 1):

Click on the right-arrow ">" at the top of the keyboard.  This will pull up a list of words.  Long press on a word and it will say "___ will be removed from learned words". Then press OK and it's gone!

Unless you are trying to remove an email address; then it doesn't disappear! :(  Really annoying.  Anyone know how to fix that?

On a Samsung Galaxy Note 4.

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to go to settings then to keyboard and open the keyboard configuration and erase the keyboard history. However if that does not work you can try erasing your cache memory in the section of memory in the configuration app.

Answer (score 0):

On my S5 I can hold down the offending word and it will ask if I want to remove it from the learned list.